# MSI: How to conditionally change installation failure text?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have an MSI packages that executes a number of deferred custom actions during product install. If one of custom actions fails, installation ends with standard "Installation was cancelled..." window. This "cancelled" text is very confusing to end user, and i want to modify it in case my custom action fails an i know what is a problem.

I have tried to queue custom action after `ExecuteAction` but was faced with a problem: this action is executed only on installation success, but not on instllation failure! After that i have tried to queue my custom action to be executed at installation failure by assigning it a sequence number of `-3`. It is executed - but in server context, so it can't change text that is displayed in client context!

Is it any way to change this text? I need a custom action that is executed in client context (immediate mode) after installation fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to use [Error Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368554%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?
(add your own error description into this table and return its code)

Comment: Wow, this looks promising. And how to set my own error code if my custom action fails?

Comment: @EyeofHell the exact details depend on the language your custom action is in (C#, or C++?), but basically you need to format an error record

Comment: @JohnL can you show example for C++, please? Custom action returns 0/1/2/3 depending on error/success/cancel/whtever, i can't figure out how to connect custom action, error table and static text in last dialog (this text is built-in into MSI, i have checked microsoft MSI packages and packages generated with WIX - i can't figure out how error table can change it)

Comment: Examples for this kind of thing are a little thin on the ground.  How did you create your project? Was it with the WiX-provided C++ Custom Action template? If so, then you might want to check out the MSMQ actions in the WiX source: http://wix.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/ext/MsmqExtension/ca/mqsched/mqsched.cpp. Search for `WcaErrorMessage`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `src\ext\UIExtension\wixlib\`**WixUI_en-us.wxl** in WIX source.
Find String ID of your text and add (for example into `Product.wxs`):

```
<String Id="STRING_ID_HERE">New text</String>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'and add'? What i need to add and where?

Comment: I mean place it in into `Product.wxs`

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not work - i need to change text `conditionally`, only in case if my custom action fails.

Comment: I'm not sure, but what if you: 1. create string variable, 2. set it's text to default 'failure text' then 3. in your CA just set to this variable new text value.

Comment: Property changed from deferred custom action (one that execute during actual install) is not accessible from client process (where dialog with installation error is displayed). This is how MSI works :(.